# Prepared satements with bind_param() in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any way to write this code using prepared statements?

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM exercises 
    WHERE exercise_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT e.exercise_id 
        FROM users u,users_subjects us, exercises e 
        WHERE u.username='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND us.user_id_fk=u.id AND e.subjects=us.subject_id_fk
    );";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

I'm trying this way, but with the sencente ‘IN’, I’m not sure how to do it:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM exercises where exercise_id in (select distinct e.exercise_id from users u,users_subjects us, exercises e where u.username='".$_SESSION['username']."' and us.user_id_fk=u.id and e.subjects=us.subject_id_fk");
$stmt->bind_param("" );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Please learn to use ANSI JOIN rather than cross-products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// use ?'s in prepare
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM exercises where exercise_id in (select distinct e.exercise_id from users u,users_subjects us, exercises e where u.username=? and us.user_id_fk=u.id and e.subjects=us.subject_id_fk");

// then pass $username to bind_param()
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
```

Then the rest of your code should work. I'd also recommend testing your stmt commands for error handling. They all return booleans.

```
// use ?'s in prepare
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM exercises where exercise_id in (select distinct e.exercise_id from users u,users_subjects us, exercises e where u.username='?' and us.user_id_fk=u.id and e.subjects=us.subject_id_fk");

if(!$stmt) echo "prepare failed: " . mysqli_error($conn);
```

Same can be done for bind_param() and execute().

Comment: `?` shouldn't be in quotes

Comment: good catch! I updated my answer.

Comment: `if(!$didPrepare)` ??? That var has nothing to do with the prepare failing or succeeding? It `= $_SESSION['username']`

Comment: [How to enable MySQLi exception mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments/22662582#22662582)

Comment: Echoing the error message right away is not how do you test for the success. Please kindly read the [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)